# Sum Aggregations in MongoDB Using Spring Data

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, aggregation-framework

this is my data

```
{"intentId" : "A1", "like" : "Y"}
{"intentId" : "A1", "like" : "Y"}
{"intentId" : "A1", "like" : "N"}
{"intentId" : "A2", "like" : "Y"}
{"intentId" : "A2", "like" : "N"}
{"intentId" : "A2", "like" : "N"}
{"intentId" : "A2", "like" : "N"}
```

and mondodb script run very good. here is  code.

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate( [
{
         $project:
           {
             intentId: 1,
             likeY:
               {
                 $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$like", "Y" ] }, 1, 0 ]
               },
               likeN:
               {
                 $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$like", "N" ] }, 1, 0 ]
               }
           }
      },
     { $group : { _id : "$intentId", likeY: { $sum: "$likeY" }, likeN:  { $sum: "$likeN" } }} 
  ] );
```

my problem is that i want to run this code under spring data

```
MatchOperation matchStage = Aggregation.match(new Criteria  ("delYn").ne("Y"));
GroupOperation groupStage = Aggregation.group("intentId");
Cond operatorNbS = ConditionalOperators.when("like").then("Y").otherwise(value)
ProjectionOperation projectStage = Aggregation.p
SortOperation sortStage = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "_id");
Aggregation aggregation   = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchStage, groupStage,projectStage,sortStage);
```

please give me a tip to solve my problem....
thanks in advance!

Comment: i cant handle condition filed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, as of now, to do it with spring. Try using DBOject instead.

```
public static AggregationOperation projectLikeNY() {
    DBObject projectYN = new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("intentId", 1).append("likeY", new BasicDBObject("$cond", Arrays. < Object > asList(new BasicDBObject("$eq", Arrays. < Object > asList("$like", "Y")),
            1, 0))).append("likeN", new BasicDBObject("$cond", Arrays. < Object > asList(new BasicDBObject("$eq", Arrays. < Object > asList("$like", "N")),
            1, 0)))

    );

    CustomAggregationOperation project= new CustomAggregationOperation(
        projectYN);
    return project;
}
```

Somewhere in your project create this CustomAggregationOperation:

```
public class CustomAggregationOperation implements AggregationOperation {

    private DBObject operation;

    public CustomAggregationOperation(DBObject operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return context.getMappedObject(operation);
    }

}
```

Instead of using ProjectionOperation use this:

```
AggregationOperation projectStage = projectLikeNY();


Aggregation aggregation   = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchStage, groupStage,projectStage,sortStage);
```

Hope this helps